# Google Drive desktop client not updating existing files from other users

Tags: windows, macos, sync, dropbox, google-drive

I've looked around and there doesn't really seem to be any troubleshooting information for the Google Drive desktop client. It all assumes you are using Google Docs on the web.

Anyway, my team is trying to use Google Drive like Dropbox, where multiple people are editing files shared amongst them through the desktop, such as images.

Dropbox is really good at noticing when a checksum for a file is changed, and syncing it. Google Drive's desktop client seems not to do this at all. Google Drive desktop client seems to only sync newly created files and not giving any notification at all that there is a modified version, it will never sync it, even though going online and opening that file will show the modified version.

Is there any way to fix this? and the answer has nothing to do with proxy or firewall configurations. Team is using computers running OSX and Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Google Drive works similar when dealing with non-google-doc files. However, for google doc files, it only stores a link to the google doc on web. Thus your actual copy is always only available online.

Comment: the drive is being used for non-google-doc files only. they are not being updated reliably if they already exist

Comment: After I noticed such issues, I switched back to Dropbox. I heard its a design shortcoming which would be fixed in upcoming releases

Comment: where did you hear about that design shortcoming? I didn't find anything from google, a lot of people are having problems with google drive not meeting their expectations, it clutters google results

Comment: You'll obviously not find it on google's product page.. But you can always google for shortcomings in gdrive. One such is http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2403713,00.asp and another here http://office-watch.com/t/default.aspx?a=1687&template=print-article.htm